# How to make groups of horizontal bars have the same color?

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, label, bar-chart

I need to plot horizontal bars using the `grouped` style such that all the bars belonging to each group have the same color but different from other groups (i.e. all bars of the top group are red, the group below it - green, and so on...).

Also, how can I put the values on the top of each bar horizontally? How can I control the position of such values?

This is my code:

```
y = [91.9 8.1 94.4 5.6; 84.9 15.1 90.12 9.88; 89.4 10.6 91.2 8.8; 72 28 50.9 49.1];

h = barh(y,'grouped'); 
job = {'group1','group2 ','group 3','group4'};
legend(job,'location','northeast');
```

This is my current figure:

[image]

Comment: @Tommaso When you edit please try to be more thorough. Although you removed some typos, there are still things that need improvement like: title, code and some more typos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a hack:
Plot bar graph for 1 row at a time and fill the space with `NaN`s while specifying a single color for all rows. Plotting `NaN`s will plot nothing.

```
[ry, cy] = size(y);   %Number of rows and columns of y
hold on;
for k = 1:ry
    tmp = [NaN(k-1,cy); y(k,:); NaN(4-k,cy)];   %Filling with NaNs
    h{k} = barh(tmp, 'FaceColor', rand(1,3));   %Plotting bar graph in random color
    h{k} = h{k}(1);   %Store handle of any of the rows (Required for legend)
end
job = {'group1', 'group2', 'group3', 'group4'}; %Required legend entries
legend([h{:}], job);  %Default location is already 'northeast' (so can be skipped)
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

Answer (score 2):

This is another type of hack; tested on R2017b.

The reason why what you're asking is difficult to do is because each group in a bar plot is actually a `Quadrilateral` object (i.e. polygon). For example, let's take the 1<sup>st</sup> `Bar` object:

```
>> h(1).Face.VertexData

ans =

  3×16 single matrix

  Columns 1 through 9

         0   91.9000   91.9000         0         0   84.9000   84.9000         0         0
    0.6545    0.6545    0.8000    0.8000    1.6545    1.6545    1.8000    1.8000    2.6545
         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0

  Columns 10 through 16

   89.4000   89.4000         0         0   72.0000   72.0000         0
    2.6545    2.8000    2.8000    3.6545    3.6545    3.8000    3.8000
         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
```

And if we add this line to the code:

```
drawnow; hold on; scatter(h(1).Face.VertexData(1,:), h(1).Face.VertexData(2,:));
```

we get (notice the green circles):

[image: Visualizing the surface]

What's interesting is that the points in `VertexData` are not read-only, which means we can just intelligently "rearrange" the `VertexData` matrices of the `N` bar groups to get the desired result. Here's one way to do it (notice I renamed `h` to `hBar`):

```
% Obtain the old VertexData:
vd_old = cell2mat(reshape(get([hBar.Face],'VertexData'),1,1,[]));
% Rearrange VertexData:
nB = numel(hBar);
vd_new = cell2mat(permute(mat2cell(vd_old,3,repelem(4,nB),repelem(1,nB)),[1,3,2]));
% Assign the new VertexData back into the Bar objects' Edge and Face fields:
for indB = 1:nB
  hBar(indB).Edge.VertexData = vd_new(:,:,indB);
  hBar(indB).Face.VertexData = vd_new(:,:,indB);
end
```

[image: After hacking]

Finally, we manually add labels using the `text` command:

```
xOffset = 1;

for indB = 1:nB
  text(double(vd_new(1,2:4:end,indB)) + xOffset, double(tmpY(2:4:end)), ...
    string(vd_new(1,2:4:end,indB)),'VerticalAlignment','middle');
end
```

The end result:

[image: End result]

The final code:

```
function q47978293
close all force;

y = [91.9 8.1 94.4 5.6; 84.9 15.1 90.12 9.88; 89.4 10.6 91.2 8.8; 72 28 50.9 49.1];

figure(47978293); set(gcf,'Position',[786,556,887,420]); hBar = barh(y,'grouped');
legend("group" + (1:4),'location','northeast');
drawnow;
% hold on; scatter(h(1).Face.VertexData(1,:), h(1).Face.VertexData(2,:));

% Obtain the old VertexData:
vd_old = cell2mat(reshape(get([hBar.Face],'VertexData'),1,1,[]));
% Rearrange VertexData:
nB = numel(hBar);
vd_new = cell2mat(permute(mat2cell(vd_old,3,repelem(4,nB),repelem(1,nB)),[1,3,2]));
% Assign the new VertexData back into the Bar objects' Edge and Face fields:
xOffset = 1; % < Adjust as you see fit
for indB = 1:nB
  hBar(indB).Edge.VertexData = vd_new(:,:,indB);
  hBar(indB).Face.VertexData = vd_new(:,:,indB);
  try
    text( y(indB,:) + xOffset, mean(reshape(vd_new(2,1:2:end,indB),2,[]),1,'double'), ...
      string(vd_new(1,2:4:end,indB)),'VerticalAlignment','middle');
  catch % Compatibility fix for R2016b & R2017a. Credit @SardarUsama
    text( y(indB,:) + xOffset, mean(reshape(vd_new(2,1:2:end,indB),2,[]),1,'double'), ...
      split(num2str(vd_new(1,2:4:end,indB))),'VerticalAlignment','middle');
  end
end

end
```

> ***Note:*** due to the hacky nature of this solution, if the figure is redrawn (due to e.g. resizing), the bar colors will return to their original state - so make sure that the part that changes colors is the very last thing you do.

---

**P.S.**
The [R2017b release notes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html?startrelease=R2017a&endrelease=R2017b&category=Graphics#mw_f1a67652-52ea-4637-850a-e7166b0459ed) state that this customization should be officially supported now (through the `CData` property of `Bar` objects), but I couldn't get the legend to display the correct colors. If you want to try it, just plot using the following command (R2017b+):

```
barh(y,'grouped','FaceColor','flat','CData',lines(size(y,1)));
```

Comment: @Tommaso Thanks! I only wish I could get it to work "the official way" (the start of which I recently added at the very end)...

Answer (score 0):

The two requests overlap making everything kinda complex, since using uniform colors for each group implies using a workaround that needs another workaround to male bar text work. Here is the code:

```
y = [
  91.90  8.10 94.40  5.60;
  84.90 15.10 90.12  9.88;
  89.40 10.60 91.20  8.80;
  72.00 28.00 50.90 49.10
];

[rows,cols] = size(y);
n = NaN(rows,cols);

c = {'r' 'g' 'b' 'y'};

bh = cell(rows,1);
lh = cell(rows,1);

hold on;

for k = 1:rows
    curr = n;
    curr(k,:) = y(k,:);

    bar = barh(curr,'FaceColor',c{k});

    bh{k} = bar;
    lh{k} = bar(1);
end

hold off;

legend([lh{:}],{'G1','G2','G3','G4'},'Location','southoutside');

yl = get(gca,'XLim');
yl_up = yl(2);
xoff = yl_up * 0.01;
set(gca,'XLim',[yl(1) (yl_up + (yl_up * 0.1))]);

set(gcf,'Units','normalized','Position',[0.1 0.1 0.8 0.8]);

for i = 1:numel(bh)
    bh_i = bh{i};

    for j = 1:numel(bh_i)
        bh_ij = bh_i(j);
        hx = bh_ij.YData + xoff;
        hy = bh_ij.XData + bh_ij.XOffset;

        text(hx,hy,num2str(hx.','%.2f'), ...
             'FontSize',10, ...
             'HorizontalAlignment','left', ...
             'VerticalAlignment','middle');
    end
end
```

And here is the output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Please, tell me how i can remove the numbers of Y axis (1,1.5,2,2.5,....ect) from this customized figure ?
i tried using

% clears X axis data
      %set(gcf,'XTick',[]); 

but not working !!

Comment: @MohsenAli *1.* Its the axis you want to change, not figure; so you'd use `gca`, not `gcf`. *2.* Furthermore, you want to make that change on y-axis, not x-axis. Hence it would be:  `set(gca,'YTick',[])` . Good luck!